# Reorganizing an excel workbook based on values in multiple columns into two columns based on header and value

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel table that I would like to reorganize:

[image]

I'd like to reorganize the table where all the headers are in one column associated with their location and their values. See image below for desired result:

[image]

These are just examples of a much larger dataset, but the task is the same. I am familiar with VBA and was wondering if anyone has had a similar problem, what functions or procedures could help reorganize my table?

Comment: No need for VBA. You can do this with a [reverse pivot table](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/creating_a_database_table_from_a_summary_table/) ... Here is possibly [an even better link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal/20543651#20543651) to do the same..

Comment: Thank you, Scott. The reverse pivot table was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing snazzy I know of to do this, just use a loop within a loop. Which ever you have fewer of (rows or columns) that should be your first loop.

Comment: this should be comment, not an answer